# How to SSH connection with Django?

Tags: django

How can I connect to a freebsd server and return commands using SSH in Django?
I tried using the paramiko library but couldn't get it to work.

*Sorry for my level of English, I'm not very good.*

Comment: Welcome! Please read the instructions first that how can you ask the best question..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.